# Two different results when dealing with Zip

Tags: python, list, zip

Let have this code in a cell:

```
    a = ['a','b','c']
    b = [1,2,3]
    c = zip(a,b)
    list(c)
```

Output : [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
Now, after that when we have the code :

```
    list(c)
```

Output : []
Why that , what happen to c variable ?

Comment: `zip` is an iterator, it only returns its results once. `list(c)` consumed them.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = [1,2,3]
c = zip(a,b)
print(list(c))
```

Call print function in order to see the output of list 'c'

Comment: If not that, then possibly explain the issue a little more?

Comment: The question (paraphrased) was *why does a zip object return an empty list when used the second time*?